# compgen does not descend into directories

Tags: bash, compgen

I have defined a bash_completion script.  There are certain cases in which I want to fallback to the basic file-based completion that happens by default for most commands.  To do this I am using `compgen`, but I can't get it to descend into sub-directories.

Imagine I am running compgen from within a directory that contains a directory called `bin`.  When I run `compgen -f bi` I am given `bin`.  I would expect this to return `bin/` which would then permit me to push TAB again to descend into the contents of the `bin` directory.  But instead, `complete` gets just one value and assumes that it has reached the end of processing.  This differs from how bash completion seems to work in general where `ls bi[TAB]` would result in `ls bin/`.

Since I can't get this to work, for the time being I have written custom code that descends into the directories to perform the correct bash completion, but there must be a way to do this with `compgen` directly.

Comment: The built-in solution to that seems decidedly non-trivial. In my system, completion for combined files/directories, as for exampled used by `cd` in the `_cd` autocompletion function, is handled by `_filedir`. In my system, that function is in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: This being said, if for my own command `mycommand` I issue `complete -f mycomm`, it properly descends into subdirectories...

Answer (score 0):

Been bashing my head against this brick wall (no pun intended).  Just realised that the trick is not in how you invoke **compgen** in your custom completion function, but how you tell **complete** to handle it, in particular you need to tell it to treat the results from your function as filenames (and thus if a directory is given, to let you descend into it):

```
complete -o filenames -F _mycmd_completions mycmd
```

Internally to my custom function, also, I am doing basically the following to match dirs and files (inc. handling for files/dirs with spaces):

```
_mycmd_completions()
{
  local IFS=$'\n\t'
  local word="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
  local values=($(compgen -d -- "$word") $(compgen -f -- "$word"))
  # Processing on values ...
  COMPREPLY=(${values[@]})
}
```